# Splicing a row into a Javascript object at an index based upon its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have a javascript object that looks like the following:

```
{
  0: [0,50],
  1: [25,50],
  2: [148,60]
}
```

How can I insert a new row at an index dependant on the value?

E.g. if the row I wish to insert contains the data [122,65] I need to test the value '122' versus the first value of all the the rows and then 'splice' the row in at the returned index. The second of each row value (50,50,50 in the example above) should not be taken into consideration. In this case the newd data should be inserted as row 2 since it is less than 148 and higher than 25... With the previous row 2 now becoming row 3.

I have been hunting high and low for an answer to this today and have stumbled across the following code which hints at the kind of functionality I am after, but does not quite work in this instance since if my understaning is correct, it only compares single numbers.

```
function findInsertionPoint(sortedArr, val, comparator) {   
   var low = 0, high = sortedArr.length;
   var mid = -1, c = 0;
   while(low < high)   {
      mid = parseInt((low + high)/2);
      c = comparator(sortedArr[mid], val);
      if(c < 0)   {
         low = mid + 1;
      }else if(c > 0) {
         high = mid;
      }else {
         return mid;
      }
      //alert("mid=" + mid + ", c=" + c + ", low=" + low + ", high=" + high);
   }
   return low;
}

/**
 * A simple number comparator
 */
function numComparator(val1, val2)  {
   if(val1 > val2)   {
      return 1;
   }else if(val1 < val2)   {
      return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I don't know if the above code will help anyone come up with a solution but I thought I would share it anyway.  I am of course open to any javascript/jQuery method of achieving this.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using an object and not an array?

Comment: It is unfortunately the nature of the app I am having to tap into.  It is not my choice.  Sadly I am not in a position to alter the way the app itself handles data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could be improved greatly, but this really is a bandaid for a bad design.

```
var myObj = {
  0: [0,50],
  1: [25,50],
  2: [148,60]
}

function makeArray( obj ) {
    var newArray = [];
    for( var x in obj ) {
        newArray.push(obj[x]);
    }
    return newArray;
}

function makeObject( newArray ) {
    var newObj = {};
    for(var i=0, n=newArray.length; i<n; i++) {
        newObj[i] = newArray[i];
    } 
    return newObj;
}

function custSortFnc(a,b) {
    return (a[0]==b[0]) ? a[1]>b[1] : (a[0] > b[0]) ? 1 : -1;
}

function addValue(val) {
    var newArray = makeArray( myObj );
    newArray.push( val );
    newArray.sort( custSortFnc );
    myObj = makeObject( newArray );
}

console.log(myObj);
addValue([122,65]);

for(var xx in myObj){
    console.log(xx + ":" + myObj[xx]);
}
```

The looping will be bad if you add tons of elements to this thing. I also did not really check the sort function, it could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks epascarello, with a couple of minor modification this does exactly what I need.  Agreed its an ugly way of doing it, but I really do have no choice and it is for such a small feature that is not performance critical that it should be fine.  At least until I can get authorisation to modify the actual app itself.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is never going to work properly as objects do not have a defined order for their properties.

Therefore, inserting a property in an *order* is not going to always work. Use an array if the order matters.

Comment: Thanks alex, I suspected as much.  However, would there potentially be a way of converting this data into a simple array, sorting it then converting it back to an object in the correct order?

Comment: @gordyr There's no order to objects, so you can't insert it back to an object in the *correct* order. The solution is to use an array instead of an object